# why doesn't deadlock occur in this situation

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, deadlock, synchronized

```
public class TestClass {

public synchronized void func1() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("func1");
        long a = System.nanoTime();
        func2();

}

public synchronized void func2() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("func2");
        long a = System.nanoTime();
        while (System.nanoTime() - a < 10000000) {
            ;
        }

        func1();

} }

public class ThreadSample extends Thread {

TestClass testClass;
public ThreadSample(TestClass testClass)
{
    this.testClass = testClass;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        testClass.func2();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}}

public class Main {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
    ThreadSample threadSample  = new ThreadSample(testClass);
    threadSample.start();
    testClass.func1();
}}
```

please look at the above code. why doesn't the deadlock occur here? because the Main thread is in func1 and wants to go to func2 but it can't because func2 is locked by ThreadSample. and ThreadSample also can't go to func1. so we should face a deadlock but we don't.

why?

Comment: (maybe I don't understand deadlock correctly) the func2 is called by ThreadSample thread so func2 is locked by ThreadSample thread func1 is called by Main thread so func1 is locked by Main thread and when ThreadSample wants to go out from func2 it should go to func1 but func1 is locked by Main thread and when the Main thread wants to go out from func1 it should go to func2 but func2 is locked by ThreadSample thread. so the deadlock should occur?
where is my mistake?

Comment: If you're not getting a deadlock, then you should be getting a stack overflow from calling the functions from each other.

Comment: Only one of the threads (the newly created one or the main one) will process through the func1/func2 calls, but will proceed without any problem.

Comment: no i don't because of the delay I made in the func2

Comment: FYI, You seem to expect the functions to be called in a certain order, but that's not a valid assumption when multiple threads are running. The main thread could call `testClass.func1()` before the other thread calls `func2()` or it could call `func1()` _after_ the other thread calls `func2()`.  There's no way to predict the order in which those calls will happen.

Comment: Deadlock (as Neng Liu said, below) requires at least two different locks.  A deadlock is when you have two or more threads, and none of them can do _anything_ (e.g., acquire a lock) until one of them does _something_ (e.g., release a lock). The simplest case (sometimes known as "deadly embrace") is when thread A has acquired lock 1 and is trying to acquire lock 2 while, at the same time, thread B has acquired lock 2, and is trying to acquire lock 1. Neither thread will release the lock it already has acquired until it acquires the other lock, but neither thread can acquire the other lock...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dead lock occurs only when there are multiple locks.

In this case, `func2` and `func1` are synchonized on the same `lock` monitor(an instance of `TestClass`). Once a thread has aquire this lock, other threads will be blocked until it releases the lock.

---

Suppose `main thread` has entered `func1`, that means it has aquired the lock, other threads **can not** call `func2` at the same time. Because `fun1` and `fun2` are working with the same lock! And in `fun1`, this thread can call `fun2` because `synchronized` block is reentrant.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace your `func2()` method with a `sleep` as shown below to hold the lock on the `testClass` object :

```
public synchronized void func2() throws InterruptedException {
    System.out.println("func2");
    long a = System.nanoTime();
    Thread.sleep(1000000000000L);
    //func1();
}
```

Now, `threadSample` thread first gets the lock (after start) waits inside `func2` (holding the lock on the `testClass` object) therefore the `main` thread can't even enter into `func1()` waiting for the lock on the same object.